# Grails installation for dummies

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, java-7

I am trying to install grails and make it work with IntelliJ, something goes wrong however. I am getting all kind of exceptions (while installing grails or compiling grails project in IntelliJ).

I am looking for a clean installation guide for grails under IntelliJ. I would like to use the following sdks if possible:

1. jdk 1.7 (05)
2. grails 2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [IDEA-86261](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86261) you need [IDEA 11.1.3](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP) or later to work with Grails 2.1.

Installation is very straightforward, just unpack the `grails-2.1.0.zip` in some directory and specify this directory when project setup wizard asks you to create Grails SDK in IntelliJ IDEA.

If you have any issues, please update the question with more details (steps you've performed, errors, logs, stacktraces, etc).

Comment: Agree with what @CrazyCoder has said, the only thing I'd add is that if you have an existing grails project created, you can generate the intellij file for it easily with the `grails integrate-with --intellij` command.  It will make the appropriate .ipr and .iml files that you can open with intellij (on the mac, just type `open *.ipr` and it'll open right up).